# How to close an established network connection?

Tags: java, android

I have to download a file in parts. For this I am using "xxx.setRequestProperty()". But I get error saying that it cannot be used when a connection is made. So I want to close the connection which was already established using download URL.

```
try {

        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        Log.d(TAG,"connected");
        int length = connection.getContentLength();
```

Now I want to close "connection". Please suggest some ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add a `finally` block after your `try` statement here and call

```
input.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

in it. You want to call these in a `finally` block to ensure that they get called regardless of whether the preceding code fails.

Comment: @tet Since you're new here, a heads up - If my answer (or anyone else's) was helpful to you, please consider accepting it (by clicking the checkmark beside it). Doing so will give you +2 reputation points, and increase the likelihood that folks will help you out in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {

// Your code here

} finally {
  if (is != null) {
    try {
      is.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Excpetion", x);
    }
  }
}
```

This way you will always close InputStream. 
Here is javadoc for android: [UrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).